# Better update management on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Windows 7 Ultimate.

Is there any way to automatically install just Windows Updates that are of a specific type?

My HTPC is really starting to annoy me with the amount of time I have to spend managing updates, restarting and generally not enjoying the HTPC.

I'm getting 4 options for settings:

- Install updates automatically (I don't want this, because sometimes updates do bad things)
- Download updates, but let me choose to install (I'm constantly getting notifications, can I set the frequency of this somewhere?)
- Check for updates, let me choose when to download and install (same as above, constantly getting notifications... frequence setting?)
- Never check for updates (I don't really want this, because it will never remind me to get updates)

The machine is connected to the internet, so ideally I could have virus definitions (the ones through Windows Update) be applied automatically, but just a notification for other updates every week or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just turn it off and use Task Scheduler to update my PC once a month.  Simple.

I personally use [this powershell](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSWindowsUpdate) module.  It's simple and easy to schedule using the Task Scheduler.  Simply turn off Update and use the module to turn it on and check for updates overnight once a month.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks for the recommendation. I'll experiment with it.

Answer (score 3):

> Install updates automatically (I don't want this, because sometimes updates do bad things)

It is a rare thing nowadays for an OS update to cause significant problems. the most likely culprits being 3rd party drivers which aren't automatically deployed via WU.

To directly answer your question: I don't believe that it's possible to configure WU to work the way you want it to.  Your best bet would be to simply let Windows Update install everything automatically and not worry about it.

Comment: I agree. Windows 7 has significantly improved how it does updates. I understand that attitude that updates can do bad things primarily stems from XP, which at that time did have lots of headaches associated with updates. Windows Vista had its own problems too but I've left Windows 7 up with updates automatically installed and never had issues.

Comment: I'd like to do this (really I would!) but I've had Windows 7 updates cripple machines more than once. This particular machine has gone unusable once which required some safe mode tinkering. For my main TV watching setup, this just isn't good enough.